# double and '^' Operator, not possible?

Tags: java, android, operators, double

I'm new here(5 days old to be exact) making basic programs in Android and Java. Here's the code I'm working on and I'm stuck at the **'else if' on sendAmount()** part of this code.

I got an error there that says "**The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) double, double**".

Now my question is, how can I make it work and display the result?

```
private EditText entPrinAmt;
private EditText entIntRate;
private EditText entTol;
private EditText entMonAmt;

private TextView txtFactor;
private TextView txtFutValue;
private TextView txtIntIncome;
private TextView txtEffRate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    entPrinAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ent_prin_amt);
    entIntRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ent_int_rate);
    entTol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ent_tol);
    entMonAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ent_mon_amt);

    txtFactor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFactor);
    txtFutValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFutureVal);
    txtIntIncome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIntIncome);
    txtEffRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEffRate);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendAmount(View view) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,###,###.##");
    DecimalFormat factorFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#####################");

    double dPA = Double.parseDouble(entPrinAmt.getText().toString());
    double dIR = Double.parseDouble(entIntRate.getText().toString());
    double dTL = Double.parseDouble(entTol.getText().toString());
    double dMA = Double.parseDouble(entMonAmt.getText().toString());

    if (dPA < 0){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence txtToast = "Must not be negative!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, txtToast, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if (dPA == 0 && dIR>0 && dTL>0 && dMA>0){
        Double resultPA;
        resultPA = ((dMA * ((1+dIR/12)^dTL-1)/((1+dIR/12)^dTL*dIR/12)),2);

        /*String f = df.format(resultPA);  <-v-DO NOT MIND THIS
        txtFactor.setText("Principal Amount: P" + f);*/
    }
    else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence txtToast = "Can't Compute Principal Amount!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, txtToast, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

BTW, I got that equation from here:

> return ROUNDOFF((nPmt*((1+nRate/12)^nPer-1) / ((1+nRate/12)^nPer*nRate/12)),2)

I think this is from C or C++ platform. I don't understand the '**,2**' part tho. How can I apply that to the class I'm working on? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` operator is bitwise xor, not power. In fact, Java has no power operator defined. You should use [`Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) instead.

Additionally, you should use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) when working with currencies, for a number of reasons you will find explained here on SO.

Comment: i really thought it's power.. ive learned something today, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in java **The operator ^ (bitwise xor) is undefined for the argument type(s) double, double**.
Use `Math.pow(double , double)` instead of `^`.

So your code will look like this:

```
resultPA = ((dMA * (Math.pow((1+dIR/12),dTL-1))/(Math.pow((1+dIR/12),dTL)*dIR/12)),2);
```

Comment: ooh thanks man! but now i got an error regarding that. says "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: You are welcome,but you have already selected your answer! Please ask a new question, not inside a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is a bitwise XOR operation, most likely you want to

```
double d = Math.pow(a, b); // a^^b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **pow** function.

```
double output = Math.pow(x,y);
```